# PHP MYSQL copy one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql

Im using php mysql and i was wondering if anyone can give me a format to copy from tableone 3 columns of data in a specific row to another table.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about PHP this is about MySQL

The query is:

```
INSERT INTO dst (field1, field2, field3) SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM src;
```

You can use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [mysql](http://php.net/mysql) to execute it in php

Comment: this looks better. Just needs to change the `field2` to `field3`

Answer (score 1):

use `insert into ... select` syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html